# CSS selector every element except those inside a particle class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select every element within a wrapper except the elements within one of the children. Consider this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="this">
        <div class="that"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="orange">
            <div class="ignore"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hello"></div>
    <div class="world">
        <div class="ignore">
            <div class="this"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to make the text color of everything inside `wrapper` white, except the elements that are inside `ignore`. What I got so far is `.wrapper *:not(.ignore *)`, which doesn't work.

EDIT: I can't accept solutions that include overriding what the color is within `.ignore` because that color is pre-set, and is out of my control. It is also impossible to know which color is used in the pre-set. Imagine there's a `body {color:blue;}`, only in my case, it's impossible to know what color it is.

Comment: just set the `color` of `.wrapper` then set the color for `.ignore`. i.e. `.wrapper { color: red; } .wrapper .ignore { color: blue; }`. Does that not work?

Answer (score 2):

Add `color: #fff` to `.wrapper`

Then, add whatever color your want to `.ignore`

After  that, make sure `.ignore` **loads after** `.wrapper` in your style sheet.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #131418;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px
}
.ignore {
  color: #933
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="this">
    <div class="that">wrapper</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">wrapper</div>
    <div class="orange">
      <div class="ignore">ignore</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hello">wrapper</div>
  <div class="world">
    <div class="ignore">
      <div class="this">ignore</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't use any solution that involves overriding `.ignore`

Comment: Would using ids on top of classes be an option?

Comment: What do you mean? There are close to a hundred elements within `.wrapper` and `.ignore`, not sure if it's viable to ID all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you put them in right order you can get this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: green;
}
.wrapper *:not(.ignore) {
  color: white;
}
.wrapper *, .wrapper .ignore *{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="this">
        <div class="that">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">2</div>
        <div class="orange">
            <div class="ignore">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hello"></div>
    <div class="world">
        <div class="ignore">
            <div class="this">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Note that `:not(...)` is applied to the current element, so you **can't use** `:not(something [some element inside])`

Comment: I can't use `.wrapper *, .wrapper .ignore *{  color: red;}` because the colors are actually pre-set already (that part is unknown and beyond my control). I won't be able to know what the pre-set color is ,so i can't override it like this.

Comment: And you want the white color to be applied to both the `div.ignore` and the childs of `div.ignore`?

Comment: No, the white color is applied to everything inside `.wrapper` *except* the elements inside `.ignore`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
.wrapper div:not(.ignore) {
  color: white;
}
```

The reason your posted CSS selector doesn't work – and shouldn't be expected to work – is because:

```
.wrapper *:not(.ignore *)
```

Is trying to select all descendent elements that are not descendants of the `.ignore` elements, whereas in your question it seems that you're trying to select only elements that are not themselves of the `.ignore` class.

Further, the `:not()` pseudo-class:

> ...is a functional notation taking a **simple selector** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

[**Emphasis** mmine, https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation].

And a 'simple selector' is:

> ...either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

[https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn]

Which appears to prevent the use of a combinator, the white-space, representing the selection of a descendant; meaning that your selector `.ignore *` is an invalid selector for the negation (`:not()`) pseudo-class.

Comment: No, I actually meant all descendants, hence "every element within".

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS doesn't seem to provide a good solution - at least not one I can think of.

The problem with `not` is it can only apply to "simple selectors", which basically means the selector it applies to can't contain combinators like whitespace.

For simple cases, you could do what a lot of people are suggesting - just have a second rule that selects `.ignore *` and undoes what your `.wrapper *` rule does.  But if the `.wrapper *` rule does a lot, or if the exact state you'd get without the `.wrapper *` rule is unclear (maybe set by an external resource) then that isn't necessarily practical.

What you could do is use JavaScript (or similar) to propagate the .ignore class down to all of its descendants, then just use `:not(.ignore)`